# The complexity of Pohlig-Hellman algorithm

Tags: discrete-logarithm, pohlig-hellman

The Wikipedia [Pohlig Hellman algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) says that the complexity of Pohlig-Hellman algorithm is

$$\displaystyle {\mathcal {O}}\left(\sum _{i}{e_{i}(\log n+{\sqrt {p_{i}}})}\right)$$

I understand that the complexity of calulating $(x \mod p_i^{e_i})$ is ${\mathcal {O}}\left({e_{i}{\sqrt {p_{i}}}}\right)$. But which part of this algorithm has complexity of ${\mathcal {O}}\left({e_{i}{\log n}}\right)$?

Comment: Look at the steps on [Handbook of Applied Chapter 3 algorithm 3.63](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf) steps 2.4. where 2.5 is the part you know. Powering is not cheap right?

Comment: A small hint: what is the cost of inversion an element?

Comment: @kelalaka could you elaborate more? I still don't understand.

Comment: Did you check the full algorithm? There is an inversion there, it highly affects the cost. Inversion is not a cheap operation.